# Extra quote marks being added to String field in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some text processing on entries in a tsv file so I loaded it in as a dataframe and I'm trying to add a quotation mark at the beginning of a certain entry in the dataframe. So the code I'm using to do this is as follows

```py
episode_info.loc[i, 'word'] = "\"" + episode_info.loc[i, "word"]
```

but the result I'm getting when I look at the output is """help" instead of just "help and the previous entry is just help so I don't know why this isn't working

Comment: '\"' + 'help' returns '"help' to me, as expect. What exactly do you have in .loc[I, 'word']?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add some of your data in your question so we can see what it looks like and what you are trying to do? This way we can help you better.

Comment: So the entire row is as follows `1 5 tinacollins help N N N N 00:00:28.597 00:00:26.800000 00:00:30.395000 00:00:26.89067 00:00:28.00533 00:00:28.60267 00:00:28.72533 00:00:29.41867 ` and the columns are `'caseID', 'sentID', 'speaker', 'word', 'killer_gold', 'other_gold', 'suspect_gold', 'human_guess', 'medion_time', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'i1_time', 'i2_time', 'i3_time', 'i4_time', 'i5_time'` and so the entry for word says just help but when I output the new tsv that uses this code the entry for word becomes `"""help"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I printed out the entries in question to terminal and it looks like it was printing out the correct thing. I guess when I viewed it in Sublime, which is what I was using, the quotation marks were being formatted weirdly. Apologies for the unnecessary question.